# File type validation on dropped files

Tags: javascript, html, fine-uploader

File type validation works fine when clicking the upload button and select files from the list. But when a file is dropped onto the drop area, any file is accepted and uploaded. No validation is done and no error is thrown.

Is there another way to validate dropped files?

Here is my code:

```
$('#avatar-wrapper .uploader').fineUploader({
    multiple: false,
    validation: {
        acceptFiles: 'image/*'
    },
    request: {
        endpoint: '/includes/fineUploader/endpoint.php'
    },
    retry: {
        enableAuto: true
    },
    callbacks : {},
    showMessage: function (message) {
        alert(message)
    }
})
```

I tested the demo, and there I did get an error message. But with my script, the files are just accepted. I also tried with 'allowedExtensions', but there is no difference.

Comment: Are you using a library? If so can you setup a fiddle with your drag drop code isolated?

Comment: Validation is working fine in all cases, as far as I can tell.  The [demos page](http://fineuploader.com/demos) confirms this.  If you'd like assistance, you'll need to show enough code to allow others to easily reproduce.